# Android.mk - Get subset of all-subdir-java-files

Tags: android, makefile

I am looking for an alternative to

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-subdir-java-files)
```

in the Android.mk file.

I have this tree structure:

```
Android.mk
---- com
---- test
```

Using the all-subdir function will get me all java files in the com **and** test package. I want a function that **only** returns the java files of the com package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under,com/)
```